# Laravel using wrong controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

[image]

Laravel generates same controller in console directory and when i render dashboard component then laravel use controller from console directory which is wrong. So if I make changes in controller then its not reflecting.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily deleting the whole Controller folder inside of Console to see if it forces it to add to the correct file structure in Http? (Please make sure you cut and paste them somewhere to save any lost work)

Comment: I have tried but its not working

Comment: Are you namespacing the controllers correctly?

Comment: I am using namespace correctly. but issue is laravel create same controller in console directory and using newly generated controller which are wrong

Comment: You might need to do `composer dump-autoload` also

Comment: thanks @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After delete controller from console directory and then fire the `composer dump-autoload` its solved my issue